# Which non-parametric regression could I apply to fit a curve to this data set?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I have posted a similar question about the same problem, having been suggested to use a polynomial Robust Linear Model, which worked fine for most cases, as can be seen here:

[Non-algebric curve-fitting along weighted pointcloud (if possible using python)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43086/non-algebric-curve-fitting-along-weighted-pointcloud-if-possible-using-python)

But since then I have done some research, and I think a Non-Parametric regression model might be a better choice, since the model must fit locally and the result should respect some conditions which are not parametric.

The problem statement is this:

"Given a data set consisting of a set of coordinates in the form (positionX, positionY, weight), representing candidate locations of simmetry points of a human back surface, 'weight' being a representation of fitness (bilateral symmetry according to some symmetry function) of each point, find the curve that most likely represent the midline of the back, possibly misaligned due to postural inadequacies, considering that:

1. The line must run along the full height of the dataset;
2. For each Y (independent variable) there should correspond X (dependent variable) representing the most probable position of the midline;
3. There is coupling between successive X positions, that is, X is not random, there are not discontinuities, for the back midline "in the real life" doesn't have discontinuities, sharp corners or points of high curvature. Therefore, the resulting curve should be reasonably "smooth and well-behaved".
4. The method should "bridge" two regions with good fit separated by a region with more locally scattered points.
5. "when in doubt", the midline tends to run along the vertical middle of the bounding box of the dataset.

I have found two articles in Wikipedia that seem to be applyable to this problem ([Kernel Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression) and [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC)), but my current knowledge is not enough (mathematical and statistical notation, programming) in not enough to solve the problem on my own. Here are two representative images found in those articles, that resemble the conditions of my problem:

RANSAC algorithm with a linear model:

[image: RANSAC algorithm with a linear model]

Kernel regression:

[image: Kernel regression]

Also, I want to provide my own data:

Sample unordered set of (x,y,weight) coordinates:

```
[[ -0.7898176   -3.35201728   4.36142086]
 [  2.99221402  -3.35201728   1.11907575]
 [  6.97475149  -3.35201728   2.4320322 ]
 [ -4.82443609  -2.35201728   0.6479064 ]
 [ -1.32418909  -2.35201728   1.88004944]
 [  0.07067882  -2.35201728   1.10982834]
 [  3.09169448  -2.35201728   1.8557436 ]
 [  7.10399403  -2.35201728   2.03906224]
 [ -3.07207606  -1.35201728   0.35500973]
 [  2.63202993  -1.35201728   5.32397834]
 [  5.19884868  -1.35201728   1.63816326]
 [  7.65721835  -1.35201728   1.13843392]
 [  2.48172754  -0.35201728   6.65584512]
 [  6.0905911   -0.35201728   1.15552652]
 [  8.62497546  -0.35201728   0.30407144]
 [ -4.7300089    0.64798272   0.31481496]
 [ -3.03274093   0.64798272   0.95337568]
 [  2.19653614   0.64798272  10.3675204 ]
 [  6.20384058   0.64798272   1.42106077]
 [ -4.08636605   1.64798272   0.28875288]
 [  2.03344989   1.64798272  13.04648211]
 [ -4.11717795   2.64798272   0.39713141]
 [  1.93304283   2.64798272  10.41313242]
 [ -4.37994815   3.64798272   0.84588643]
 [  1.66081408   3.64798272  14.96380955]
 [ -4.19024027   4.64798272   0.73216113]
 [  1.60252433   4.64798272  14.72419286]
 [  6.77837359   4.64798272   0.6186005 ]
 [ -4.14362668   5.64798272   0.93673165]
 [  1.55372968   5.64798272  12.9421123 ]
 [ -4.62223541   6.64798272   0.6510101 ]
 [  1.527865     6.64798272  10.80209351]
 [  6.86820685   6.64798272   0.82550801]
 [ -4.68259732   7.64798272   0.45321369]
 [  1.36167494   7.64798272   6.45338514]
 [ -5.19205787   8.64798272   0.23935013]
 [  1.21003466   8.64798272  10.13528877]
 [  7.6689546    8.64798272   0.32421776]
 [ -5.36436818   9.64798272   0.79809416]
 [  1.26248534   9.64798272   7.67036253]
 [  7.35472418   9.64798272   0.92555691]
 [ -5.61723652  10.64798272   0.4741007 ]
 [  1.23101086  10.64798272   7.97064105]
 [ -7.83024735  11.64798272   0.47557318]
 [  1.20348982  11.64798272   8.20694816]
 [  1.14422758  12.64798272   9.26244889]
 [  9.18164464  12.64798272   0.72428381]
 [  1.0827069   13.64798272  10.08599118]
 [  6.80116007  13.64798272   0.4571425 ]
 [  9.384236    13.64798272   0.42399893]
 [  1.04053491  14.64798272  10.48370805]
 [  9.16197972  14.64798272   0.39930227]
 [ -9.85958581  15.64798272   0.39524976]
 [  0.9942501   15.64798272   8.39992264]
 [  8.07642416  15.64798272   0.61480371]
 [  9.55088151  15.64798272   0.54076473]
 [ -7.13657331  16.64798272   0.32929172]
 [  0.92606211  16.64798272   7.83597033]
 [  8.74291069  16.64798272   0.74246827]
 [ -7.20022443  17.64798272   0.52555351]
 [  0.81344517  17.64798272   6.81654834]
 [  8.52844624  17.64798272   0.70543711]
 [ -6.97465178  18.64798272   1.04527813]
 [  0.61959631  18.64798272  10.33529022]
 [  5.733054    18.64798272   1.2309691 ]
 [  8.14818453  18.64798272   1.37532423]
 [ -6.82823664  19.64798272   2.0314052 ]
 [  0.56391636  19.64798272  13.61447357]
 [  5.79971126  19.64798272   0.30148347]
 [  8.01499476  19.64798272   1.72465327]
 [ -6.78504689  20.64798272   2.88657804]
 [ -4.79580634  20.64798272   0.36201975]
 [  0.548376    20.64798272   7.8414544 ]
 [  7.62258506  20.64798272   1.52817905]
 [-10.50328534  21.64798272   0.90358671]
 [ -6.59976138  21.64798272   2.62980169]
 [ -3.71180255  21.64798272   1.27094175]
 [  0.5060743   21.64798272  11.06117677]
 [  4.51983105  21.64798272   1.74626435]
 [  7.50948795  21.64798272   3.46497629]
 [ 11.10199877  21.64798272   1.78047269]
 [-10.15444935  22.64798272   1.47486166]
 [ -6.26274479  22.64798272   4.73707852]
 [ -3.45440904  22.64798272   1.72516012]
 [  0.52759064  22.64798272  12.58470433]
 [  4.22258017  22.64798272   2.63827535]
 [  7.03480033  22.64798272   3.506412  ]
 [ 10.63560314  22.64798272   3.56076386]
 [ -5.95693623  23.64798272   2.97403863]
 [ -3.66261423  23.64798272   2.31667236]
 [  0.52051366  23.64798272  12.5526344 ]
 [  4.21083787  23.64798272   1.95794387]
 [  6.82438636  23.64798272   4.77995659]
 [ 10.18138299  23.64798272   5.21836205]
 [ -9.94629932  24.64798272   0.4074823 ]
 [ -5.74101948  24.64798272   2.60992238]
 [  0.52987226  24.64798272  10.68846987]
 [  6.29981921  24.64798272   3.56204471]
 [  9.96431168  24.64798272   2.85079129]
 [ -9.64229717  25.64798272   0.4503241 ]
 [ -5.579063    25.64798272   0.64475469]
 [  0.52053534  25.64798272  10.05046667]
 [  5.79167815  25.64798272   0.92797027]
 [ 10.05116919  25.64798272   2.52194933]
 [ -8.55286247  26.64798272   0.94447148]
 [  0.45065604  26.64798272  10.97432823]
 [  5.50068393  26.64798272   2.39645232]
 [ 10.08992273  26.64798272   2.77716257]
 [-16.62381217  27.64798272   0.2021621 ]
 [ -9.62146213  27.64798272   0.62245778]
 [ -7.66905507  27.64798272   2.84466396]
 [  0.38656111  27.64798272  10.74369366]
 [  5.76925402  27.64798272   1.13362978]
 [  9.83525197  27.64798272   1.18241147]
 [-15.64874512  28.64798272   0.18279302]
 [ -7.52932494  28.64798272   2.94012191]
 [  0.32171219  28.64798272  10.73770466]
 [  9.4062684   28.64798272   1.41714298]
 [-12.71287717  29.64798272   0.70268073]
 [ -7.59473877  29.64798272   2.16183026]
 [  0.20748772  29.64798272  12.97312987]
 [  3.92952496  29.64798272   1.54987681]
 [  9.05148017  29.64798272   2.40563748]
 [ 14.96021523  29.64798272   0.55258241]
 [-12.14428813  30.64798272   0.36365363]
 [ -7.12360666  30.64798272   2.54312163]
 [  0.40594038  30.64798272  12.64839117]
 [  4.59465757  30.64798272   1.23496581]
 [  8.54333134  30.64798272   2.18912857]
 [-10.6296531   31.64798272   1.4839259 ]
 [ -7.09532763  31.64798272   2.0113838 ]
 [  0.37037733  31.64798272  12.2071139 ]
 [  3.01253349  31.64798272   3.01591777]
 [  4.64523695  31.64798272   3.50267541]
 [  8.39369696  31.64798272   2.53195817]
 [ -7.07947026  32.64798272   1.01324147]
 [  0.39269437  32.64798272   9.67368625]
 [  8.58669997  32.64798272   1.00475646]
 [ 12.02329114  32.64798272   0.50782399]
 [-10.13060786  33.64798272   0.31475653]
 [ -7.30360407  33.64798272   0.35065243]
 [  0.49556923  33.64798272   9.66608818]
 [ -5.37822311  34.64798272   0.38727401]
 [  0.4958055   34.64798272   7.5415026 ]
 [  6.07719006  34.64798272   0.63012453]
 [ -4.64579055  35.64798272   0.39990249]
 [  0.46323666  35.64798272   4.60449213]
 [  4.72819312  35.64798272   0.98050594]
 [ -4.62418372  36.64798272   0.64160709]
 [  0.48866236  36.64798272   4.29331656]
 [  5.06493722  36.64798272   0.59888608]
 [  0.49730481  37.64798272   1.32828464]
 [ -1.31849217  38.64798272   0.70780886]
 [  1.70966455  38.64798272   0.88052135]
 [  0.06305774  39.64798272   0.47366487]
 [  2.13639356  39.64798272   0.67971461]
 [ -0.84726354  40.64798272   0.63787522]
 [  0.55723562  40.64798272   0.62855097]
 [  2.22359779  40.64798272   0.33884894]
 [  0.77309816  41.64798272   0.4605534 ]
 [  0.56144565  42.64798272   0.43678788]]
```

An image showing one very good fit (leftmost), and two fits that I consider not good, all from different subjects, obtained by fitting a Polynomial Robust Linear Model, acoording to the previously linked question: (the middle fit "jumps" out of the main midline, while the rightmost runs a long length parallel to the "true" midline instead of right through it)

[image]

It seems to me that, being parametric and global, polynomial models end up being sensitive to interfering conditions present in the current problem domain.

I thank for any help and in special to the fellow who answered the previous question, which took me out of a dead-end and presented me the amazing `statsmodels` Python module, which I would like to keep using if possible with a non-parametric regression approach.

Comment: If you just want the fitted line to follow the center points, why are you including the other points in the model? Basically, can you explain why you think the other points are important for your estimate, and what effect you think they should have?

Comment: @JonathanChristensen These additional points come around as an undesired results of not knowing previously which is going to be the right point. The dataset is generating by taking successive horizontal cross sections of the back surface model. If a point is found to be laterally symmetric, it is included as a candidate, with a weight proportional to its "symmetricness". Some parts of the back (and some whole backs) give a nice string of high-weight points around the middle, but I cannot be sure of that beforehand, unfortunately...

Comment: I don't understand why the selection of center points that I used in the previous question doesn't work in the second and third case. They look very close to me. Kernel Regression in itself is not robust and will not fit the center line. However, lowess is a robust version. Worth a try: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html

Comment: @user333700 Thanks again, lowess seems to be very adequate. Unfortunately I'll be able to test it just tomorrow. The algorighms you provided in the previous question are fine, I think the main concern is that the problem itself is best represented by a non-parametric regression (in the second and third fittings on the drawings, I considered the fit as 'not adequate' because clearly the best fit, if drawn 'by hand' should be over the central blue dot string. One possible reason could be an unstable first 3rd order fit (not plotted).

Comment: My impression is that the nonparametric part is not really relevant for the question, whether it's polynomials, splines, kernel functions, all of them will get "bent out of the way" if you don't put almost all the weight on the center points in the estimation. The main question, I think, is to find the settings so that a robust estimator puts most of the weight on the center points automatically.